# Strange behaviour with dateutil.parser

Tags: python, date, parsing

May someone explain me why I have this behaviour with the 't' parameter

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse('t')
```

> Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 28, 0, 0)

When I except :

```
parse('z')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   [...]
>   ValueError: Unknown string format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t` is a special case since it is one of the ["jump" values](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/master/dateutil/parser.py#L251) (it's usage while parsing is [here](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/master/dateutil/parser.py#L1031)):

```
JUMP = [" ", ".", ",", ";", "-", "/", "'",
        "at", "on", "and", "ad", "m", "t", "of",
        "st", "nd", "rd", "th"]
```

In other words, parsing `t`, `m` would not result into an "Unknown string format" error.

The `z` is a *special case* too since it can have a [special meaning](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/master/dateutil/parser.py#L366)  - "zulu"/"zero offset" (which is part of the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), but that does not affect the results much, `parse("q")` or `parse("u")` would also produce an "Unknown string format" error.

---

Both `parse("t")` and `parse("z")` would result into a default/current date in "fuzzy" mode:

```
>>> parse('t', fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 28, 0, 0)
>>> parse('z', fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 28, 0, 0)
```

Comment: https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/master/dateutil/parser.py#L251
you gave me the answer, the JUMP parameter

Comment: @And0rian yeah, the answer was not complete without the "jump" part. Thanks to you, you have figured that out.